# Can't create new core because of Caused by: _version_ field must exist in schema and be searchable

Tags: solr

I have a json file that I'm trying to index into Solr that is specified like this:

```
{"word" : "str", "word_list" : ["word1, "word2"], "word_form": ["word form"]}
```

I want to index on the field word and have the documents be word_list and I'm getting confused on how to do this. I started by trying to define a new schema.xml but I'm not sure why it's throwing the error

```
Caused by: _version_ field must exist in schema and be searchable
```

EDIT: HERE IS THE ENTIRE SCHEMA

I've created a schema.xml that looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.5" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema name = "lookup" version="1.5">
<fields>
<field name="word" type="string" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="similar_words" type="string" stored="true" required="true"/>
<field name="word_forms" type="string" stored="true"/>
 <field name="version" type="string" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
</fields>
<uniqueKey>word</uniqueKey>
<types>
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField"/>
</types>
</schema>
```

I try to create the core in the GUI but it throws the error

```
Error CREATEing SolrCore 'new_core': Unable to create core [new_core] Caused by: _version_ field must exist in schema and be searchable (indexed or docValues) and retrievable(stored or docValues) and not multiValued (_version_ does not exist)
```

Comment: add a field in schema.xml as <field name="_version_" type="string" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/> or something like <field name="_version_" type="plong" indexed="false" stored="false"/>

Comment: Yes I tried that but it still throws the same error.

Comment: after the changes ...did you restart the server?

Comment: yup, tried restarting the server same error.

Comment: Update your schema, post the updated schema here. Remember that Solr will use the managed schema if present. The field needs to be `stored` and indexed - use `docValues="true"` for the field if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Add below entry in your schema.xml.

```
"<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>"
```

"**version**" is must entry from Solr 6.6 onward I guess so you must add and try.